# Local or Push Notification consumes less energy?

Tags: ios4, power-management

I want to use notification and i have read that Local and Push Notification is basely same, only difference is that push notification is

> remote notification

The info comes from outside, and local Notification is local.I have also read that Push consumes 20% of battery usage.My question is that the Local notification is better in battery save or not?

thanks

Comment: I would bet money on local notifications being much more efficient since there's no network traffic - but I'll leave this to someone more knowledgeable to give a definitive answer. However, I'm curious where you got the information that push notifications "consumes 20% of battery usage". Do you have any references for this?

Comment: Yes but i think 20% is of battery usage of program, i have read it in slovak forum, if you can translate it here is the link: http://www.mobilmania.sk/clanky/iphone-os-30-oficialne-predstaveny-ponuka-push-notifikacie-ci-mms/sc-3-a-111060/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in both the cases it depends on the implementation and number of notifications user receives.

Push Notifications seems to consume lesser than the local notifications. But if the user has huge friends list (for example), then he/she would probably be getting lots of notifications and probably (as per your implementation) lots of notification alerts as well, then in this case even the Push Notifications consume good amount of power.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, or if there is it's miniscule.  In order to have notifications of any sort the device must "wake up" from time to time.

Since, in the general scheme of things, it's got to monitor for phone calls, messages, and push notifications for other apps, it's regularly "listening" for messages.

Likewise, many operations inside the device are based on timers, so the device is always running a timer and always ready for a time interval to expire.

Once the push notification has been received or the local notification timer has gone off, the logic inside your app is virtually identical, so there's no difference there.

The biggest difference would likely be on the setting side, but that could go one way or the other depending on how your app sets up notifications.